# How to rewrite the request path to point to another path under the same domain with webpack-dev-server?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

What I want to achieve is to change the request URLs in the format of `/**/locales/**/*.json`, e. g. changing from `some.domain.com/subpath/locales/another/file.json` to `some.domain.com/locales/file.json` using webpack-dev-server. My configuration was working fine some days ago but now I got a EHOSTUNREACH error, after moving my code and finally reverting back to the original working implementation now I get a ETIMEDOUT error.

```
<e> [webpack-dev-server] [HPM] Error occurred while proxying request some.domain.com/locales/file.json to https://some.domain.com/ [ETIMEDOUT] (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)
```

I'm using my hosts file to resolve the some.domain.com. My actual configuration is:

```
const HOST_DOMAIN = 'some.domain.com'

return {
  devServer: {
    server: { type: "https" },
    port: 443,
    compress: true,
    allowedHosts: "all",
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    },
    client: {
      webSocketURL: `auto://${HOST_DOMAIN}/ws`,
    },
    proxy: {
      '/**/locales/**/*.json': {
        target: 'https://' + HOST_DOMAIN,
        pathRewrite: function (path) {
          const parts = path.split('/');
          return '/locales/' + parts.pop();
        },
        secure: false
      }
    },
    static: [
      {
        directory: path.join(__dirname, "src/locales"),
        publicPath: `/locales`,
      },
    ],
  },
  // ...
}
```

I have tried to set the `originRewrite` to true as well, but it didn´t work.

Is it possible to achieve this? If so, is this the righ way? I don't know why it stopped working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the `proxy` option can be used to achieve the URL rewriting in  my use case, I found it's not its mainly purpose and can bring limitations and add more complexity to the original problem.

Therefore, the [`historyApiFallback`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverhistoryapifallback) option is more suitable for rewriting URLs and serving static files as noted in the documentation.

Then, the webpack configuration result in something like this:

```js
const path = require("path");

// ...
devServer: {
  historyApiFallback: {
    rewrites: [
      {
        from: /^\/([^/]+)\/locales\/(.+\.json)$/,
        to: context => `/locales/${path.basename(context.parsedUrl.pathname)}`
      },
    ],
  },
  // ...
}
```

The above will intercept all requests in the format of `/**/locales/**/*.json` and use the `to` property to [rewrite the URL](https://github.com/bripkens/connect-history-api-fallback#rewrites), which in my case is using a function that reads the URL from the `context` object and extracts the filename to create the correct path where the static files are served from.